# HTA Document.Body.OffsetHeight with doctype

Tags: internet-explorer, hta

Please consider this HTA:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My HTML application</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="My HTML application"
  ID="MyHTMLapplication"
  SCROLL="No"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">

Sub Window_OnLoad

  ResizeTo 100, 100
  msgbox Document.Body.OffsetWidth & "x" & Document.Body.OffsetHeight

End Sub

</script>

<body style="border:0;margin:0"></body>
</html>
```

On my PC it reports: **111x66** and that's actual size of window without window frame.

Now if I add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to this HTA, I get: **107x19** where width is actually correct, but not the height.
If I even want to use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE">` I get: **107x0**

My HTA depends on doctype, and I can't remove it. OTOH I want to be able to detect actual window size and act upon it.

Can someone explain why `Document.Body.OffsetHeight` behaves like this, or maybe provide other solution for detecting correct window size (body element size)?

Comment: Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503242/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-hta-window?

Comment: I saw it now, but it uses same variable `Document.Body.OffsetHeight` which, as I reported, doesn't contain meaningful value when used with doctype declaration - it always returns same value regardless window size.

Answer (score 0):

By default HTA is in backward-compatibility mode where `document.body.offsetWidth` and `document.body.offsetHeight` return expected result.

With doctype declaration HTA turns in standards mode (CSS1Compat) in which case this should be used instead: `document.documentElement.offsetWidth` and `document.documentElement.offsetHeight`